# Can I use z-index in jquery to determine order of .show()?

Tags: jquery, z-index, draggable, show

I am somewhat new to JQuery so apologies if there is an obvious answer to this question.

I am experimenting with creating an "About Me" page for my website. I have several paragraphs all occupying the same position on the page. Only the top paragraph with the z-index: 3 is initially visible. The others are set to display: none. When the first paragraph is dragged, the next paragraph with the z-index: 2 becomes visible. You can see here: http://www.clare-eileen-callahan.com/aboutme/

There are two more paragraphs with z-index: 1 and z-index: 0 that are still hidden. I would like for each paragraph to successively become visible each time the user drags the visible paragraph with the next higher z-index. However, I am not sure how to get jquery to do this. I'm guessing there is some way to get each paragraph to appear one by one by indicating z-index...?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
            <p class="draggable" id="univText">I am a sixth year Ph.D. candidate in the Department of English at Duke University. My research examines late 19th to mid-20th century novels that trouble the relationship between representation and various forms of political and economic abandonment, particularly poverty and forms of working-class labor. My work incorporates Marxist geography, feminist and queer theory, and biopolitics. I have more recently begun to study media theory and digital knowedge. Move me to read more about my work as a "digital humanist."</p>

            <p class="draggable" id="webDevText">My interest in coding arose out of my participation, from 2012-2014, in the <a href="http://sites.fhi.duke.edu/phdlab/" target="_blank">PhD Lab in Digital Knowledge</a>, run out of the Franklin Humanities Center at Duke University. I began learning how to write code through <a href="www.codeacademy.com" target="_blank">Code Academy</a> and the <a href="http://thewc.co/" target="_blank">Women's Coding Collective</a>. I simultaneous began to study documentary photography at the <a href="http://documentarystudies.duke.edu/" target="_blank">Center for Documentary Studies</a>, also at Duke. Out of these two new fields of study, I became increasingly interested in multimedia and web development, as well as media theory. In the summer of 2014, I attened the <a href="http://sct.cornell.edu/" target="_blank">Summer School for Criticism and Theory at Cornell</a>, where I was a participant in a seminar on media theory. Relevant coursework includes classes and workshops in digital photography, web-based multimedia development, and multimedia documentary. You can also follow my progress at <a href="http://www.codecademy.com/clareeileen" target="_blank">Code Academy</a>. This about me page is mainly for the purpose of experimenting with jquery and javascript.</p>

            <p class="draggable" id="paraText">I am a USPA licensed skydiver with over 300 skydives. I began skydiving in 2003, and became a USPA rated Coach in 2014. I work with students who have graduated from AFF training, as well as with young licensed jumpers. I am a member of <a href="http://www.uspa.org/USPAMembers/SistersinSkydiving/tabid/551/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Sister's in Skydiving (SIS)</a>, an organization devoted to increasing the number of women in the sport and providing guidance to female jumpers new to the dropzone.</p>

            <p class="draggable" id="advMap">See my adventure map. <span id="click_me">&#x2192;</span></p>
            <iframe id="here_i_am" src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zYpTz5XLDQCk.kzQAVkxbygAE" width="350" height="350"></iframe>
        </div>
```

My relevant CSS:

```
#univText {
    position: absolute;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 185px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#webDevText { 
    position: absolute;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

#paraText { 
    position: absolute;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

#advMap {
    position: absolute;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 0;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: 65%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
}
```

And my current Jquery (I have "#webDevText" set basically for the purposes of testing to see if I could get any of it to work. I'm simply not sure where to go from here):

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable", this).draggable({ //makes text draggable
        stop: function() { //when user stops dragging
            $("#webDevText").show(); //action
        }
    });
        });
```

There may also be another answer that does not involve z-index. I'm interested in any and all options.

Comment: instead of using `$("#webDevText").show();` try `this.next().show();`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I wrote it as $(this).next().show();

Comment: Great! I am posting the answer, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `$("#webDevText").show();` try `$(this).next().show();`

**Explaination**: 
Using jquery selector to identify the element is a trick here.

in your code you have used ID selector `#webDevText` everytime your code will execute it will search for element with ID `webDevText` and set its property `display:block`

Now you want to display every next element on drag stop event. There fore we will be using `.next()` selector from jQuery. Everytime when you will drag an element the every next element will be set as `display: block`.

Your code should look like below:

```
$(function() {
$(".draggable", this).draggable({ //makes text draggable
    stop: function() { //when user stops dragging
        $(this).next().show(); //action - updated with new code
    }
});
    });
```